# How to use Linq To Sql to get Users who has less than 2 photos?

Tags: linq-to-sql

The scenario is I want to get the users who has less than 2 photos.

There are two table:

```
[Users] (UserId, UserName) 

[UserPhotos] (PhotoId, PhotoName, UserId)
```

UserId is a Foreign Key but I do not want to use association like user.Photos.

A user may have none photo in the [UserPhotos] table.

How to use Linq To Sql to get `List<User>` who has less than 2 photos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this: (**fixed** version)

```
List<User> users = UserPhotos.GroupBy(i => i.UserId)
                .Where(i => i.Count() > 2).Distinct()
                .Join(Users, o => o.Key, i => i.UserId, (o, i) => i)
                .ToList();
```

solution for changed question:

```
    List<User> result = Users.Where(user => !UserPhotos.GroupBy(i => i.UserId)
            .Where(i => i.Count() >= 2).Distinct()
            .Any(i => i.Key == user.UserId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Oh, there is a bug: the result missed the users who has none photo.
I edited the question, get the users who has less than 2 photos.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this??

```
var query = from u in dbContext.Users
            where u.Photos.Count > 2
            select u;
```

That would be the easiest by far - why do you want to specifically **not** use this method??

Comment: Because there is no FK in the old-app, and I can not add a FK.

Comment: You could lazy-load the photos that are associated with the user inside the Users Model. This will allow the above functionality...